# Need to print countries using USD dollar in Restcountries API

Tags: javascript, api, filter

I tried to print the countries using US Dollar in Restcountries API (`https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all`). I tried but nothing shows as an output:

My code as follows

```js
const getUSDollar = () => {
  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhr.open("GET", "https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all", true);

  xhr.responseType = "json";

  xhr.onload = () => {

    const data = xhr.response;
    const datas = data.filter((value) => {
      for (var i in value.currencies.name.USD) {
        if (i === "Unites States Dollar") {
          return true;
        }
      }
    }).map((value) => value.name);
    console.log(datas);
  }
  xhr.send();
};

getUSDollar();
```

Please look into this.

Comment: Can you share the response/data from api?

Comment: @Danielprabhakaran N  The API link (https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all) is valid.  It give a big JSON object with currency data.

Comment: Try printing what you are getting from the response.  The object is so large it is causing jsfiddle to freeze but it is having trouble parsing the JSON.

Comment: @Andy Sorry! new here

Comment: @DanielprabhakaranN I need to print the countries using Us dollars. API link is working.

Comment: @eglease i want to retrieve the countries using USD. as of now nothing is printing. empty array

Comment: I might be wrong but looking at the JSON data, you may need `value.currencies.name` and compare that to the dollar.

Comment: Can you try this `for (var i in value.currencies["USD"].name)...`

Comment: `"currencies":{"MYR":{"name":"Malaysian ringgit","symbol":"RM"}}`  so `"MYR"` is the value.  Not sure even if you need the `name`.  Are there any countries with `USD` currency that is not the US Dollar?

Comment: @eglease Let me try

Comment: @yes many countries currencies are not USD

Comment: @DanielprabhakaranN not working

Comment: but if the currency is already `"USD"`, do you still need to check if the name is `"United States Dollar"`?  According to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_4217 it is not.  I think you should only check for `"USD"`.

Comment: @eglease yes need to check USD and print the countries

Comment: try ```for (var i in value.currencies.name)
                {
                    if(i === "USD"){
                        return true;
                    }
                }```

Comment: @eglease for me its not working! is it working for u?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this

```
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const data = xhr.response;
    const datas = data
      .filter((item) => item?.currencies?.USD?.name === "United States dollar")
      .map((value) => value.name);
    console.log('datas', datas);
  };
```

As @eglease suggested, you don't need to check the name, you can just check for USD and filter the obj like this,

```
  xhr.onload = () => {
    const data = xhr.response;
    const datas = data
      .filter((item) => item?.currencies?.USD)
      .map((value) => value.name);
    console.log('datas', datas);
  };
```

It worked for me. Try and comment whether this is what you are expected or not?
[image]

Comment: It worked for me.